# How to detect user's language in Microsoft Teams for Microsoft Bot Framework?

Tags: botframework

I want to get the user's language to use as my default Bot's language from their Microsoft Teams Application both the web and desktop version.

We already tried to do it via `os-locale` but that didn't work as desired. We also tried to use `@microsoft/team-js` but it threw a `window object is not defined` error.

Is there any other way that I can set the bot's language to the user's preferred language in their Microsoft Teams application?

Comment: as far as I know, Teams doesn't support localization. You can ask the user for a preferred language and save it in userState.

Answer (score 1):

Per the MSTeams team (as of 25 Feb 2019):

> Localization based on user culture/locale is not supported in
>   Microsoft Teams Apps. We don't have a timeline to share yet.

Comment: It has been 1 year, is it still the same way (of not being supported)

Do you have any link where same can be confirmed? Thanks...

Comment: And another 2 years ^^